# При смене 80 порта Apache на другой, возникает ошибка: Port 80 in use by “Unable to open process” with PID 4!

Tags: apache, xampp

Через `httpd.conf` поменял:

`#Listen 12.34.56.78:80` на `#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080`
`Listen 80` на `Listen 8080`
`ServerName localhost:80` на `ServerName localhost:8080`.

Нажимаю **Start** запускается но выдает ошибку (на картинке).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое бывает когда запущены другие программы что слушают  80 порт. Чаще всего это скайп, выключаете их и все гуд.

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok проблема в другом - он настроил порты в httpd.conf и скорее всего не поставил их в конфиге xampa, т.е. xamp пытается обратиться к порту 80, хотя конфиг apache настроен на порт 8080

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего Вы не изменили порты в config XAMPP.

В панели управления нажмите на кнопку "*Config*", в открывшемся окне нажмите на кнопку "*Service and Port Settings*" и в новом открывшемся окне поставьте новые значения портов. После этого запустите Apache.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

**Пошаговая инструкция по смене портов:**

1) Вам нужно открыть Apache "httpd.conf" файл и настроить его на использование/прослушку на нового порта.

Чтобы открыть файл "httpd.conf", нажмите кнопку "*Config*" рядом с Apache кнопкой "*Start*" и кнопкой "*Admin*". В появившемся меню, нажмите и откройте файл "httpd.conf":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) В файле "httpd.conf" сделайте поиск по слову "Listen". Вы найдете две строки с чем-то вроде;

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

Измените порт 80, на новый порт, который Вы планируете использовать (например порт 8080), как показано ниже:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 8080
```

3) Далее, в том же файле "httpd.conf" найдите "ServerName localhost:" Измените порт 80 на выбранный Вами порт(8080):

```
ServerName localhost: 8080
```

4) Сохраните и закройте файл "httpd.conf".

5) Теперь нажмите кнопку "*Config*" Apache снова и откройте файл "httpd-ssl.conf".

6) В файле "httpd-ssl.conf", найдите "Listen". Вы сможете найти:

```
Listen 443
```

Измените его, чтобы слушать новый порт(но не порт 8080). Например, так:

```
Listen 1443
```

7) В этом же файле "httpd-ssl.conf" найдите строку "». Измените значение порта на свой новый порт для ssl (1443).

7) Кроме того, в том же "httpd-ssl.conf" найдите еще одну строку "ServerName". Вы найдете что-то вроде:

`ServerName www.example.com:443` или `ServerName localhost: 433`

Измените значение порта `ServerName` на новый выбранный порт для ssl(1443).

8) Сохраните и закройте файл "httpd-ssl.conf".

9) В заключении измените сервисные настройки XAMPP. Для этого, нажмите и откройте кнопку "*Config*" в панели управления XAMPP. Затем нажмите кнопку "*Service and Port Settings*". В открышемся новом окне, нажмите на вкладку "*Apache*", и введите и сохраните новое значение в поле "*Main port*" и "*SSL port*" коробки. Нажмите кнопку сохранить и закройте параметры конфигурации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь нажмите кнопку "Start" Apache, и если все пойдет хорошо, Ваш сервер Apache должен запуститься.

Comment: все сделал как написали. когда запускаю все ок, но пишу в браузере http://localhost/ выдает это Not Found HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: @NursultanKenzhegaliyev уточните пожалуйста версию, которую Вы используете

Comment: XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2 [Compiled: Nov 12th 2015]

Comment: @NursultanKenzhegaliyev попробуйте выполнить команду `netstat -ano` в cmd, прослушивается ли новый порт ?